Chamberlian garage opener trolley rail bouncing up and down
Has anyone had an opener with a newer square-style trolley rail and it bounces too much? If yes, were you able to fix it or reduce the bouncing, and how?
I have a Chamberlain door opener that I installed in 2017. It's your basic chain drive unit. The previous opener was new in '94 and used a solid "T" type trolley rail. It was one piece, very sturdy. The new opener has worked reasonably well until recently. Now the door is not always able to shut. Almost as if the safety sensor was tripped. The bottom of the door gets within 18" of the ground then reverses back up. I tried a few times so I could watch it closely. I see the square trolley rail bouncing quite a bit as the door travels down. These square rails with multiple seperate sections only connect together with pressed-in tabs holding them. This translates to lots of flex compared to a solid T-rail!
Particular details that might matter:

I've applied fresh white lithium grease on all the door hinges and track wheel assemblies. Also the trolley rail, motor sprocket and some on the chain itself.

About a month ago I replaced both springs (yellow) and mounting hardware after one of the springs let go (while I was in the garage too!), and the safety cables as well :-) . (Original opener had yellow springs so I replaced with the same)


I watched several videos where the root problem for a door not closing is typically something to do with the hinges or wheels not being lubricated. Can't see that as my issue here as I've definitely applied fresh white lithium grease at the same time I installed the new springs. Also, some mentioned they found that both springs didn't match or one was old and other was new. That's not the case here either. I feel like this issue is possible due to wear and tear of the square rail. Maybe it's developed more wiggle room over time.
If I can't figure this out soon I was thinking to possibly go buy a 10' length of square metal tube (matching dimensions), cut to length and match all the mounting points.
Thanks for any ideas!

The tubing rails are definitely a bit less rigid than the old style, but it shouldn't be a problem if you're door's in good working order. Did you properly balance it such that it remains static when disconnected from the opener and opened halfway? Also, how you apply grease matters. Hinges are usually oiled, since it's difficult to get grease along the pin shaft internally, etc.

How is the door to use with the opener disconnect cable pulled?

What do you mean by "bouncing", can you post a video?  Have you checked that it's installed properly and nothing is loose that should be tight?

Thanks all! Finally had an evening to go over the whole unit top to bottom. I think I found the problem :-) The rail bounces just enough so one pulley attached to the track would twist by a 1/4" & get stuck. It became thoroughly wedged crooked, binding the cable. Thankfully I had spare parts from the kit I bought recently. Turns out that pulley lost some ball bearings at some point. I found one under a nearby cabinet. Swapped out the bad pulley, reattached the cabling and voila! It works again. The trolley is still bouncing more than I'd like, but the door is functional once again.

You can buy one-piece trolley rails for Chamberlain motors from local suppliers. They are not easy to find online because they can't be delivered easily.  If your multi-piece rail is definitely defective it would be a good idea to replace it with a better one and also make sure the new one is installed properly.  You should try to determine why your rail is behaving that way.  They are a little cheaper and less sturdy than one-piece but not to the extent you describe.  Something went wrong, and you want to know what.
There are lots of reasons the door might stop on the way down so fixing or replacing the rail may not cure that.
Building your own trolley rail from scrap sounds like an unrewarding project with a steep learning curve that can never be reused and a red flag when you sell your house.

thanks. Looks like I have it fixed (see my comment above). I do believe the bouncing rail might have caused the bearings to fail over time. If I can locate a one-piece trolley rail I'll probably swap this one out.
